# Gas-fired water heater safe to have in living area of home?

Tags: water-heater, code-compliance

A un-licensed renovation on our house was performed about 15 years ago, which turned a former garage into a 200 sq ft den directly attached to the rest of the house.  In this den is a gas-fired water heater.  It is not enclosed, and still has all the same venting it had prior to the renovation.

Is having a gas-fired water heater in a living area legal according to the Florida building code?  Or to get right to the real point, is this a carbon monoxide hazard?

Comment: I have no specific knowledge about Florida but in many parts of the country yes hot water heaters are in living spaces.  Basements, closets,etc but it’s still living space—sharing the same air, and not contained by a firewall.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), maybe you should really be asking about the problem that caused you to ask this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding local building codes are off-topic per the help center.

Comment: @Tyson My problem is that I'd prefer not to die of carbon monoxide poisoning if I can help it.  I will add that to the question, and remove the emphasis on codes.

Comment: Keep in mind that gas ranges / stoves / ovens are always found in living spaces. Water heaters and furnaces are typically found in attics or garages, but not always

Comment: In my part of the country hot water heaters are mostly always in the basement with no special measure taken for gas models, other than proper venting.

Comment: We also have unvented free standing gas fireplaces in the living space.

Comment: Postscript: legal or not, I never felt safe about having a potential CO source in the living space and eventually changed it out for an on-demand electric water heater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the gas appliance is vented properly, it is not a CO hazard. Venting is vital to ensure combustion products (i.e., CO) do not remain in the living space. If you are in doubt, get the water heater checked by a professional.

Carbon monoxide detectors are also required by code - one on each floor and outside each set of bedrooms. But, perhaps counter-intuitively, do not place a CO detector close to the water heater (or any other gas appliance); doing so can lead to false positive readings / alarms.

Answer (score 0):

This was very common as natural gas became much more common in the US in the 50's. It was the fastest way to install gas water heat. Not that some modern fool might not write a building code against it. As new homes were built, the heaters were move to basement or garage.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mechanical code a water heater may not obtain combustion air from a living space. If the water heater was not venting properly or was burning rich you could have carbon monoxide problems.  A properly functioning water heater however almost doesn’t even need a vent (but I would never try it) since it burns so clean. Kind of like a gas stove.  While it is not right I don’t know that I would freak out about it. Garages are okay as long as they have sufficient cubic footage, other rooms may be okay as well as long as not designed living space. This rule changed relatively recently(last 25 years or so) so many homes do not comply with the new code.  As with all building codes, they are just recommendations for localities to follow. They are under no obligation to follow some or all of them but they will have their official policy documented. My locality took 99% of the book and changed a couple of codes to local liking. Los Angeles scrapped the National code all together and made their own although most codes parallel the national code. In most cases you will go by either city or county policy depending on where you live.

Answer (score 0):

According to UNI 7129 regulations yes, it's regular to have a direct vent (category B) gas appliance if is present a 'permanent vent' calculated according the following formula: *vent_aperture_size [cm^2] = 6 x appliance_rated_power [kW]* if result is bigger than 100cm^2, else 100cm^2. Gas usage is not allowed in bedroom or bathrooms. According to Florida laws I don't know, but I'll put a carbon monoxide sensor or I'll switch to class-C (sealed chamber) appliance so there's no link between fire chamber and living-space (both inlet and exhaust are directed outside) -> back-drift is impossible (so no risk of CO poisoning)